# XPages Java corruption issue

Tags: java, lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I have noticed that when performing Design refresh in 8.5.3, Java classes often get corrupted and this results in issues on my XPages using the Java code (I generally get error that the package is not found/not recognized). Has anyone else noticed similar issues with Java classes and XPages? Due to the frequency of design refreshes and template being on a different server, it's not possible to do a design replace at the moment. I am also not sure if design replace will fix my problem.

Any tips, advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like the problem I used to have when the java classes are stored in the new java design object instead of adding them directly to a folder using the package explorer. not sure if that has been fixed.

Comment: I've found that doing a design refresh from the server console is pretty much bullet proof. Before that I often had the problems you described doing the design refresh from DDE.

Comment: Thanks Thimo - But if I do a design refresh on the console, I need the templates on the server itself or can I have template on another server and still initiate design refresh on the server console?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I have had issues with both options, the Java element is the worst culprit, but I have had issues with java classes added to the folder as well.

Comment: Pipalia, as far as I know you must have both on the same machine. The way I'm working most of the time as that I have both databases on the development server and I replicate the design changes back to the live server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be hit by a situation that I was hit by.

Does your application use any classes from the extension library (either the openNTF version or the IBM version - Update Pack 1)?

If so, the problem could be caused by not having the extension library installed on all computers that open the design in Domino Designer. I had this issue and found that just opening the design "touched" the Java classes (i.e. compiled them or at least signed them). This was due to the default setting in Domino Designer under "Project" to "Build automatically". So just opening Domino Designer from another computer without the extension library to adjust e.g. a form or @-formula agent, the Java classes were broken!!

It took us a little while to find out exactly why this happened. By disabling the "Build automatically" option we could avoid harming the code just by opening the database in Designer. However, a better approach is to install the extension library on all Domino Designer clients.

But be carefull since this issue can still harm your application since the elements get signed by the last user opening the design... :-(

/John

Comment: +1: I can confirm, that if someone with Domino Designer without or with obsolete version of ExtLib does design refresh/replace, application will be unusable. Even with auto build turned off.

Comment: I think this might be an issue worth investigating and fixing, since recent versions jump to designer if a end user wants to create a simple agent!! Thank you John and thank you Frantisek for the confirmation.